# Drupal permission resticted to own node in relation to another one

Tags: nodes, users

I have a pretty nasty problem with events and venues in Drupal. Let say that registered user can add a venue - there is no restrictions. Now I want to make users able to add an event but this one can be assosiated to users own venue not to others. How to limit this access?

I have both events and venues as nodes.

Any ideas?

Cheers
Pawel

Comment: I think that you can use a view to limit the options for the reference, in which case you can just create a view of the user's venues.  This is assuming, of course, that you are using [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference).

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. This is very nice idea! Have to try it.

Comment: Did it - works perfect BUT there is another problem - it affects admin as well.

Comment: This is always a tricky thing to set up.  What are you using as your argument?  If you can use PHP, then you can write code to the effect of: "If I'm creating a node, filter by the user ID of the logged in user.  If I'm editing a node, filter by the user ID of the node author".

Comment: Im using an ID logged user argument. Unfortunately I don't feel well in PHP so can't write this kind of code. I'm thinking about some kind of "admins referrence field" but don't know if it brings me another problem :)